# What is the purpose of the symbolic device file named with the HCTL address in the bsg folder

Tags: debian, centos, devices, scsi

["/dev/bsg – This folder is for Block Scsi Generic drivers."](https://www.linux.org/threads/what-are-those-dev-files.9142/) I'm not sure what that means.

There are two symbolic device files named with HCTL addresses in that folder, but from what is stated above, this is about block devices, so why are these symbolic devices?

> [root@zs /]# cd dev
> [root@zs dev]# cd bsg
> [root@zs bsg]# ls -l
> crw-rw----. 1 root root 251, 0 1:0:0:0
> crw-rw----. 1 root root 251, 1 2:0:0:0

Comment: What are the devices? Perhaps run: lsblk --output=NAME,HCTL